# What's the lowest HD Giant of at least Huge size?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, creature-size

Have a Large character, with the Giant Blood racial trait, and want to use *alter self* to transform into a Huge Giant (or a huge Humanoid, I guess, but that seems unlikely to exist without templates). What's the Huge Giant with the lowest HD? Are there even any with 5 or less, or will I have to wait for *polymorph*?

Comment: What kind of character is it exactly? A humanoid with a template?

Comment: @Peregrin Using the Savage Species version of Half-Ogre base race, which is of Humanoid type but also counts as a Giant for magical effects. Dragon Magazine also has a template version of Half-Ogre that works exactly the same, though I'm not using it for this character. Note that Half-Ogre was updated to 3.5 in Races of Destiny, which changed their type to Giant and doubled their LA; I'm closing my eyes and pretending that doesn't exist for this build.

Comment: Thanks for giving this extra information. But where does ist say that the Savage Species Half-Ogre is of humanoid type? As far as I can see, it is is simply a giant type creature.

Comment: Doesn't explicitly list their type at all, but since they're half-ogre and half-human and probably aren't Giant type (otherwise why have the Giant Blood racial trait?), I think it's a very safe assumption that they are Humanoids.

Comment: Oh my gods no you're right, it lists their type as Giant in the table at the start of that section. Well, that sucks for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Phaerlin Giant, 8 HD

The [Phaerlin Giant](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Phaerlin_giant) is a breed of giant descended from stone giants and found in the Underdark. It appears in *Monsters of Faerûn*.

It is a CR 3 Huge Giant, and has 8 HD. I dont think there is one with 5 or less HD.

*Alter Self* will not work, as it maxes out at 5HD, and even though it works on *you* with a Giant race template, it does not work on a target form with a template. Otherwise, you apparently could turn into a 5 HD Huge Half-Scrag Giant Gar. Neither will *enlarge person* work as that doesn't work on giants, but you could use the psionic power *expansion* (Thanks to @HeyICanChan for these additional points).

Answer (score 7):

#### Blunderbore Mauler (8 HD)

Jointly at 8 HD with the phaerlin giant is the Mauler, a sub-type of Blunderbore from the Diablo II crossover sourcebook *To Hell and Back* (2001).

Comment: Oh _wow_ that is a **deep** cut. Very nice.